# Slide Back Gesture on Nav Bar with Left Bar Button

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to be able to slide back a view controller that has a left bar button on the navigation bar.

There are a lot of Stack Overflow posts addressing this, and for the most part they all say to use the back button item instead of a left bar button, but that is not what I want to use. Using this line of code:

> self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate =
>   nil

allows you to retain the back swipe gesture while using a left bar button, but it ends up causing a lot of random UI issues. I was thinking it might be possible to retain the back slide gesture by using a pan gesture recognizer, but I'm not sure how to go about doing so, that's what slide out menus tend to do.

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: What does your existing code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a swipeGesture to your View as follows:

```swift
let swipeRightGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleSwipeGesture(_:))

swipeRightGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right

view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRightGesture
```

Your `handleSwipeGesture()` method should then contain the code to pop your `ViewController`.

If you want the swipe gesture to be on the `NavigationBar` instead, add the gesture like this:

```swift
navigationController.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRightGesture)
```